# Changing content in a div when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change a div content box when a link above that box is clicked. I added a click function to the individual buttons then the corresponding dive containing the content for that particular box should be displayed.

When I apply the jQuery to the page, the content does not change according to the link that is clicked and the page displays awkwardly.

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSb/) I'm working with. 
The webpage I'm working with is [here](http://types4u.org/ema/new-members.php).

Place where am i making the mistake.

The jQuery I'm working with so far looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').load('#answer1');
})

$('.question2').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').load('#answer2');
})

$('.question3').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').load('#answer3');
})

$('.question4').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').load('#answer4');
})

});//end of ready
```

The HTML I'm working with looks like this :

```
 <div class="new_member_box">
                            <a href="#" class="question1"><h4>Vision</h4></a>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="new_member_box">
                            <a href="#" class="question2"><h4>Church History</h4></a>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="new_member_box">
                            <a href="#" class="question3"><h4>Becoming a Member</h4></a>
                        </div>  

                        <div class="new_member_box">
                            <a href="#" class="question4"><h4>Pastor-in-Training</h4></a>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear" class="question"></div>
                    <div  id="answer1">
                        1
                    </div> 

                    <div  id="answer2">
                        2
                    </div> 

                    <div  id="answer3">
                       3
                    </div> 

                    <div  id="answer4">
                        4
                    </div>   

                    <div class="new_member_box_display" id="question">
                        Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load()` loads an external file with ajax, not elements on your page. You're probably just trying to hide and show elements :

```
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
    $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
    $('#answer' + numb).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, i tried it, but it did not work. When I clicked on of the buttons, content of the div box did not change.

Comment: @Olubunmi - it's a bit unclear what it is you're tying to do, but I added a fiddle to show it working ?

Comment: Thank you. One more thing : How can I set a default text in the div box when page loads/refresh ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle that does what I think you're looking to do. There are cleaner ways to do it, but this should work.
http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSb/6/

Basically you want to set the inner html of one element to the inner html of another, like this:

```
$('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer1').html());
})
```

instead of this:

```
$('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').load('#answer1');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want the text to change when you click, try this.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer1 ').text());
});

    $('.question2').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer2').text());
});

    $('.question3').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer3').text());
});

    $('.question4').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').text($('.answer4').text());
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/PZnSb/7/embedded/result/